# Quantum systems: three-level vs qutrit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, atomic-physics

Is there a difference between a three-level atomic system and a qutrit? If yes, please tell me what it is and how to relate both quantum systems.

Comment: For me the 3-level atomic system can be used to represent a qutrit, or a qutrit can be realized by a 3-level atomic system.

Comment: Thanks. But I noticed something concerning potential transitions between the levels. Do you think it has something to do ?

Comment: I understand the transition between different levels as a way to achieve logical operation on the qutrit.

Comment: It looks like all transitions are available for a three-level atomic system, while only some can be within a qutrit. What is your opinion. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In a qutrit, every transition between pairs of levels is independent, in the sense that $\vert 1\rangle \leftrightarrow \vert 2\rangle$ is independent from $\vert 1\rangle \leftrightarrow \vert 3\rangle $ which is independent from $\vert 2\rangle\leftrightarrow \vert 3\rangle$.

Thus, not every three-level system is a qutrit.  For instance, the angular momentum states with $\ell=1$ do not form a qutrit if we restrict the observables to angular momentum operators, since, for instance the matrix elements $\langle 1,-1\vert L_- \vert 1,0\rangle =
\langle 1,0\vert L_-\vert 1,1\rangle=\sqrt{2}$, i.e. the transitions between adjacent levels are not independent.  In addition, a pulse resonant for the $m=-1\to m=0$ transition is also resonant for the $m=0\to m=1$ transition: in the case of $\ell=1$ states, not very transition can be accessed independently so it's NOT a true qutrit.

Unfortunately too many people do confuse a spin triplet for a true qutrit.  This is because the states
$\{\vert 1,m\rangle\}$ **do** span the space, but the difficulty is with the operators: when restricted to angular momentum operators, not every transition can be accessed separately.  You need to use the full set $su(3)$ operators acting between basis states to properly described a qutrit.

An important and useful way to see the difference between angular momentum and $su(3)$ operators is that the standard ladder operators in $su(3)$ connect only **1** pair of states, whereas angular momentum operators connect two pairs of states when $\ell=1$.

Comment: "When restricted to..." ─ so don't. The spin triplet isn't a *useful* qutrit because come of the transitions are hard to implement using the initial toolbox, but that doesn't mean it's not a qutrit.

Comment: what definition of "qutrit" are you going with? Why should not being allowed to perform arbitrary gates/operations on it imply that you can't call such a system a "qutrit"? People talk of qudits all the time even if they can't apply arbitrary operations on them.

Comment: @glS it's semantics but what's the point of having a qutrit if *in principle* you can't apply arbitrary operations on them?  To pick up on Emilio's phrasing: not a terribly useful qutrit.

Comment: I agree with the (lack of) usefulness, I just disagree with the terminology. I don't think there's a commonly accepted definition of "qutrit" that is anything but a "state in a three-dimensional space"

Comment: in my space the qutrit with equally spaced levels is just a spin-1 (or $L=1$) system, to avoid confusion.  Agreed there is no commonly accepted definition, but using spin-1 or $L=1$ is (at least I think) more precise.